# Tip tap does not show bold or italic text when the color is also set

Tags: vue.js, tiptap

I am using Vue Tiptap with the Color extension.
After an edit, I am getting the HTML and storing it in Firestore. However, the editor does not show bold or italic text when a color is also set. However, it does show up correctly in the HTML, which is fetched by another wesbite.

Here is my editor code:

```
    <div class="editor">
        <div class="controls">
            <button @click="() => {
                editor?.chain().focus().toggleBold().run()
            }">
                &#119809;
            </button>
            <button @click="() => {
                editor?.chain().focus().toggleItalic().run()
            }">

                &#8520;

            </button>
            <VDropdown placement="top">
                <button>

                    &#127912;

                </button>
                <template #popper>
                    <div class="color-controls">
                        <div class="color-choices">

                            <div v-for="color in colors" :key="color"
                                @click="editor?.chain().focus().setColor(color).run()">
                                <div class="circle" :style="{ backgroundColor: color }"></div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button @click="editor?.chain().focus().unsetColor().run()">Remove Color</button>

                    </div>
                </template>
            </VDropdown>


        </div>
        <editor-content :editor="editor!" />
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { Color } from '@tiptap/extension-color';
import { TextStyle } from '@tiptap/extension-text-style';
import StarterKit from '@tiptap/starter-kit';
import { EditorContent, useEditor } from '@tiptap/vue-3';

const colors = [
    "Red",
    "Orange",
    "Yellow",
    "Green",
    "Blue",
    "Indigo",
    "Violet",
    "Black",
    "White",
    "Gray",
    "Pink",
    "Brown",
    "Aqua",
    "Coral",
    "Lime",
    "Maroon",
    "Navy",
    "Olive",
    "Purple",
    "Teal"
];


Color.configure({
    types: ['textStyle'],
})

const props = defineProps({
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    contentEditable: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
    },


})

const emit = defineEmits(["update:content"])

const editor = useEditor({
    extensions: [
        StarterKit,
        TextStyle,
        Color,
    ],
    content: props.content,
    editable: props.contentEditable,
    onUpdate({ editor }) {
        emit('update:content', editor.getHTML())
    },
})


</script>

<style scoped>
strong span {
    font-weight: bold !important;
}


.color-controls {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.color-choices {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}
</style>
```

In this screenshot, the word 'assorted' is set to bold. It showed up bold. Then I set the color to green, and the bold does not show.

[image: Editor not working correctly]

In this screenshot, the client site is displaying the HTML. It shows the bold and color correctly.

[image: Website works correctly]

I need the editor to accurately show the bold and italics even when the color is set.

Here is an example of the editor HTML with color and bold in the inspector:

[image: Editor Inspector]

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing seems related to CSS specificity rules, where the color attribute (set as inline styles) is overriding the bold and italic styles.

You can try resolving it by adding CSS rules to make the bold and italic styles more specific:

```
.editor-content span[style*="color"] strong {
    font-weight: bold !important;
}

.editor-content span[style*="color"] em {
    font-style: italic !important;
}
```

If this doesn't work, consider creating a custom Tiptap extension combining TextStyle and Color features.

Hope this helps!